# Material Design input-field like label only

Tags: material-design, angular-material2

I have a form which is filled with input fields and some custom components.
I use the `labels/placeholders` of the input fields as field topic, however these seem to work only for `input` elements. What if I want to have the same for `md-slide-toggle` for example?
Here is an example [enter link description here](https://plnkr.co/edit/NXuL8nJCk63NuEI1xjth)

Want `Blacklist` label to be shown as `Name` label.

Comment: that is not possible by design

Comment: Maybe subscribe [here](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/4672)? Or just style the label yourself

Comment: I attempted to style it, however the result wasn't the same. Will keep trying though. Thanks guys.